# Explanation about apparent jump and subsequent fall of VUAA ETF (Sep-Nov 2021)

Tags: etf, standard-and-poors-500

Serious newbie here with regard to ETFs that track the S&P500, but I was considering investing in VUAA.

I was just wondering if someone could explain the large jump there was on Mon Sept 13 and then a subsequent fall back on Monday November 15. I've been searching online but I haven't found anything. I was under the impression that it is (more or less) the same as VUSA (albeit that VUAA accumulates dividends). However I noticed that VUSA didn't have the same price swing which concerns me as I'm looking for something reasonably steady to invest in.

[image: 1]

Comment: I'm not seeing any jumps on those dates on several sites. Where are you seeing jumps? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: VUSA did pay a dividend on Sep 9th so I'm guessing whatever site you're looking at did not adjust for the dividend properly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, just posted a screenshot...I was searching on Google

Answer (score 2):

It's bad data - I've looked on Yahoo, Vanguard, Marketwatch, Bloomberg, and none of them show that jump.

You can also see that the "52-week high" is 86.73, which is more evidence that the jump to over 100 is false.

It's not uncommon to see bad data from time to time, especially for less popular instruments. Aggregation sites like Google track millions of securities, so there's bound to be bad data mixed in that hasn't been corrected.

Comment: Thanks for this, really appreciate it. I should have checked more reputable sources.